# put listview in data report vb6

Tags: vb6

i need to print my listview and put it into data report

this the code of data report

```
Set DataReport1.DataSource = rs   
DataReport1.Sections("section1").Controls("text1").DataField = "name"
DataReport1.Sections("section1").Controls("text2").DataField = "code"
DataReport1.Sections("section1").Controls("text3").DataField = "evalmark"
DataReport1.Show 1
```

and this code for listview

```
 Function add2()
 L1.ListItems.Add , , rs.Fields("name").Value
 L1.ListItems(L1.ListItems.Count).SubItems(1) = rs.Fields("code").Value
 L1.ListItems(L1.ListItems.Count).SubItems(2) = rs.Fields("evalmark").Value
 End Function
```

Comment: whats the error you're getting?

Comment: i don't have errors , i just need the way that i can print listview items or put the listview items into data report!

Comment: What is the result of `DataReport1.Show 1`?

Comment: It's show  all database feilds 
i want just the listview items

Comment: You can create a recordset on the fly, populate it with the values from your listview and then assign that to the report datasource, or you can open the recordset with a query that returns only the records you want.